# Is storing just username in a cookie bad practice

Tags: javascript, security, cookies, credentials, persistent-storage

In the App we are passing `UserName` value to a Internal `API`.

Before making a `Ajax` call to `API`, I am calling a function named `GetUserName()` like below. This function basically stores username in a [cookie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29986657/persist-variables-between-page-loads). I don't want to always make `Ajax` calls to server to get the UserName.

**Code:**

```
function GetUserName()
{

//TODO

1. If UserName Cookie exist, return it.
2. If UserName Cookie doesn't exist, then make Ajax call to server to Get 
   UserName and set the Cookie.

}
```

As said [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5232379/how-to-save-login-credentials-using-javascript) storing username and password in client side is bad practice.

But would like to know is it bad practice to store just username in a cookie for this scenario ? Or should I encrypt the `UserName` ?

Any help would be great.

Comment: Since username is (usually) a _**public**_ info, I don't see any reason against

Answer (score 0):

Well the user can (and will) edit the cookie and use another user's username eventually.
If that GetUserName function is purely cosmetic go ahead, but if you use it for something session-related you are asking for trouble
See OWASP [section](https://github.com/OWASP/CheatSheetSeries/blob/master/cheatsheets/Session_Management_Cheat_Sheet.md) of session IDs and security on cookies if you plan to do that.